# Geoserver WMS error with large Bounding box crossing the international dateline.

Tags: geoserver, wms

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
<ServiceException code="internalError">
Rendering process failed Angle 13,168,124,524.119 is too high.
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

the request looks like this:

```
http://mydomain.com:8083/geoserver/GeoNorth/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&STYLES=&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=GeoNorth:Northern_Clip_PHR_20140730_Pyramid,GeoNorth:Southern_Clip_PHR_20140727_Pyramid,GeoNorth:Southern_Clip_PHR_20150624_Pyramid&WIDTH=1573&HEIGHT=923&SRS=EPSG:3857&BBOX=-23369219.7435007,4845493.601471966,-7979082.720454264,13876069.87119343
```

This request which is smaller but still way larger than the image bounding boxes works:

```
http://mydomain.com:8083/geoserver/GeoNorth/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&STYLES=&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=GeoNorth:Northern_Clip_PHR_20140730_Pyramid,GeoNorth:Southern_Clip_PHR_20140727_Pyramid,GeoNorth:Southern_Clip_PHR_20150624_Pyramid&WIDTH=1484&HEIGHT=877&SRS=EPSG:3857&BBOX=-18247804.17811192,8610145.67081433,-14617962.578906432,10755274.432608945
```

I have two geoserver instances an older 2.7.2 version and a 2.8.2 server. The 2.8.2 returns the above error when the bounding box crosses the international datelne. The 2.7.2 server worked until I restarted it. Now it's returning the same error.

Any suggestions?